# How I can pass user input between php files?

Tags: php, html

Now I have Simple email Login form

```
<form action="one.php">
<input type="email" name="email"/>
</form>
```

**one.php** is email filter gmail users and header them to a custom path

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];

if (stripos($email, '@gmail.com') !== false) {
    header('Location: ../gmail/index.html');
} else {
 header('Location: /unknownusers');
}
?>
```

now we done with the first page 
my question is
how can I email name to another page' example in /gmailusers

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
<font>Welcome back,</font>
<?php
include 'one.php'; 
  echo $email; ?>  
</div>
</body></html>
```

$email will not work in this because one.php doesn't have saved info

how I can make this

> welcome back 'User.Email@gmail.com'

in **index.html** file

Can any body help me with the php code.

Comment: You can use sessions to store the variables and use them in any other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to not use `location` redirection, but just include the file you want to show.

### one.php

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];

if (stripos($email, '@gmail.com') !== false) {
    include "gmail.php";
} else {
    header('Location: /unknownusers');
}
```

### gmail.php

(This file would replace gmail/index.html because most server configurations won't pass .html files to the PHP processor.)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div> 
<font>Welcome back, <?php echo $email; ?></font>
</div>
</body></html>
```

In this case, one.php shows the gmail user what gmail.php dictates, and redirects other users to the unknownusers page.

If you want the 'login' to be persistent (so your server remembers who this person is), you'll need a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Comment: You're welcome.  If you find a question to be useful, please vote it up or click the checkmark to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing doesn't make sense, but to get it working, in `two.php` replace...

```
echo $email;
```

with

```
echo $_POST['email'];
```

**HOWEVER** You're reloading the page in `one.php`, so the code change above should never be executed.  (Why are you doing that?)  Anyway, if security is not an issue, in `one.php` you can pass the email to the other pages by doing this...

```
header('Location: ../gmail/index.html&email='.$_POST['email']);
```

then, in the `index.html` file, you access the variable `$_GET['email']`.

If security is an issue, this gets more complicated.

Comment: when i add &id= gives me The requested URL Not Found

Comment: Add `?id=`.  The `&` is used to separate variables.

Comment: thanks btw for help but i used file put & get and worket better

Comment: OK, but writing to disk is 1,000's of time slower than passing data in any other way.  You may have a convenient solution, but it's very slow.